# How can EDT be -4:00?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, jquery-countdown

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.17)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Time.zone
 => (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) 
1.9.3p194 :002 > Time.now.in_time_zone
 => Tue, 18 Sep 2012 14:16:00 EDT -04:00 
1.9.3p194 :003 > wtf....
```

Unless all of my apps are doing this (only have one to test right now) how can EDT be -04:00 from UTC instead of the normal -05:00

Whatever is causing this -04:00 is causing my deadline based app to have all the countdown timers NOT appear for anyone other than EST users.  Like if you selected CST in my app, saved, and then viewed the same page again, you'd have one hour less on the countdown... so if the gig was going off in an hour and you did it, well you wouldn't be able to join.

Not good.

Thoughts?

Comment: EDT is always -04:00. **EST** is -05:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDT ([Eastern Daylight Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Daylight_Time)) is GMT -4:00

If you look at the result, you're seeing EDT rather than EST (which is GMT -5:00).

Comment: thank you for the learning point.  At least now I can google to see wtf is going on given this new info. thanks.

Comment: my new question i guess is, if I store EST in the database, how does this field then now to go to EDT when it's in the 8month window? thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest storing things with Timezones. I would store them in GMT and then calculate the date upon retrieval based on the user's settings.

Comment: This is inherited code, I usually do leave things in GMT myself, hence the silly question about EDT... first time seeing it.  However, you say 'based on the user's settings' do you mean their local machine handles it, if it's not in the DB?